# jQuery not working from onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, my jQuery seems not to be working. I have a Javascript function --  TogAddCancel() -- called from the onClick attribute of an input "btnAddCncl," and the function is designed to toggle the value of the button. It works fine without jQuery, but doesn't execute at all with jQuery. Any thoughts?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Without jQuery:

```
function TogAddCancel() {

    var x = document.getElementById("btnAddCncl").value;
    if (x=="Add") {
        document.getElementById("btnAddCncl").value = "Cancel";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("btnAddCncl").value = "Add";
    }

}
```

With jQuery

```
function TogAddCancel() {

    var x = $('#btnAddCncl').val();
    if (x=="Add") {
        $('#btnAddCncl').val("Cancel");
    } else {
        $('#btnAddCncl').val("Add");      
    }
}
```

TogAddCancel() is called from:

```
<cfinput type="button" id="btnAddCncl" name="btnAddCncl" onClick="TogAddCancel()">
```

Comment: If you're working with the clicked element, use `this` instead of `$("#itsID")`

Comment: Checked the console for errors?

Comment: yuo have a > sign in the script tag before 'src'. Thus failing JQuery to load.

Comment: also missing quote at `onClick="TogAddCancel()">`

Comment: Sorry for the typos. Those were not present in the production version. (i.e., the code is clean, but it still doesn't work with jQuery). It works fine in the non-jQuery version.

Comment: Many thanks, j08691. I checked the console and had the following two issues:

Comment: 1. "Blocked loading mixed active content "http://ajax.googleapis . . . "  and then 2. ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: I did a search on those errors, and it seems there are workarounds involving lowering the security level on the browser. The strange/crazy thing is, the jQuery worked fine in a standalone script I tried, so my browser is not blocking it in the standalone script, only in this one (if indeed this is a "blocking" problem).

Answer (score 3):

Your script tag is incorrect. Try:

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit**

If your typos are cleaned up and it still doesn't work, you can also try using [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) with jQuery:

```
$('#btnAddCncl').click(function() {
    var x = $('#btnAddCncl').val();
    if (x=="Add") {
        $('#btnAddCncl').val("Cancel");
    } else {
        $('#btnAddCncl').val("Add");      
    }
});
```

No need for an onClick.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Figured it out! It was as simple as changing the "http:" in the src="http:// . . . " to "https:// . . . "